# Snap windows to parts of the screen on Windows 8.1 using keyboard shortcuts like Ubuntu Unity

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts, window-manager, ubuntu-unity

In Ubuntu, with the Unity desktop environment, one can move and resize applications by using the following keyboard shortcut: CTRL + ALT + 0-9 (on the Number Pad). Ctrl Alt 1 moves the current window to the bottom left corner of the screen, Ctrl Alt 2 moves the current window to the whole bottom half of the screen, Ctrl Alt 3 moves it to the bottom right, etc.

However, to my knowledge, no such function (window resizing all around the screen via keyboard) innately exists in Windows 8.1. At least, I haven't been able to find any.

How can one move/resize applications in Windows 8.1 like one can in Ubuntu's Unity?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! You will probably get better expertise on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com). Please flag your question for it to be migrated there or to be closed. Please do not cross-post. You may post on AskUbuntu once you delete your question or it gets closed.

Comment: @ubashu Thanks for the welcome! I think the answer below is sufficient (for me, anyway), so I won't request a migration, but I appreciate the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 and later provide the following keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> snaps the window to the left and right side of the screen, respectively.
- <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> maximizes the window, or restores it if it is minimized.
- <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> minimizes the window, or restores it if it is maximized.

You cannot snap windows to corners in Windows 7, 8, or 8.1.

However, Windows 10 allows you to do so by pressing <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> while holding <kbd>Windows</kbd> after snapping to the left or right. Furthermore, you can use the arrow keys while holding <kbd>Windows</kbd> to freely move windows to different sides or corners of the screen. Note that Windows does not support snapping to the top or bottom halves.

Windows 10 also supports virtual desktops, which can be used to organize windows as you can with workspaces in Unity and many other Linux desktop environments.

(Side note: As of this writing, you have **five days left** to upgrade to Windows 10 for free. Have you looked into taking the free upgrade?)

Comment: Yup, this works for me with Windows 8.1. Unfortunately, it's not exactly like Unity, but it's close enough. The Windows 10 features look compelling though, and I will check it out while it's free. Thanks.